# Is there any service in AWS which would start and stop the instance at particular time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance and I want to stop at 12:00 am at night and start it again at 7pm everyday.Is there any AWS service by which I could achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are enough examples on this, you can follow the official links of aws for doing this.

If you are looking for a simple solution I would suggest doing it using AWS lambda and cloudwatch https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/start-stop-lambda-cloudwatch/

If you are looking for a robust solution, then as mentioned in earlier doc follow https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/stop-start-instance-scheduler/

Comment: Hi,I just tried the cloudwatch solution.I am able to stop the instance using EC2 stop instance API call but there is no API to start the instance.

Comment: @daveMiller, I am assuming you are using the lambda, and below is the code to start ec2 `using lambda import boto3
region = 'us-west-1'
instances = ['i-12345cb6de4f78g9h', 'i-08ce9b2d7eccf6d26']

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
    ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
    print 'started your instances: ' + str(instances)`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply.Is it free of cost?

Comment: @daveMiller, if you are using the free-tier and using lambda only for this, then its more than enough, you can see the details on pricing here https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/ and good part is first 1M REQUESTS FREE

Comment: Just another thing. Is there any cost for using cloud watch service to trigger it?

Comment: @daveMiller , you can look at the detailed pricing here https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/pricing/ , if you are using only for this, It would not be there or very minimal.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways to do this.

1. Create an ASG with timed scaling events. Scale to 0 instances at 12:00 AM and 1 instance at 7:00 PM. That's super easy!
2. Use CloudCustodian and create a custodian policy.
3. Use the reference arch here: https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/instance-scheduler/

Comment: First of your solutions will terminate / create instance on schedule. Although this is a good practice, seems like the question was about stop / start operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using Two approach, Two lambda functions or you do that using one but for that, you may need to check trigger time and second is bash script using AWS CLI with cron job.

**Using Lambda:**

1. Lambda function to stop instance at 12:00 AM
2. Lambda function to start instance at 7 PM

**Important** thing both Lambda should be based on scheduled event. Remember that the time is in **UTC**.

[image]

1.To Stop

```
region = 'us-west-1'
instances = ['i-12345cb6de4f78g9h', 'i-08ce9b2d7eccf6d26']

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
    ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
    print 'stopped your instances: ' + str(instances)
```

2. To start

```
import boto3
region = 'us-west-1'
instances = ['i-12345cb6de4f78g9h', 'i-08ce9b2d7eccf6d26']

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
    ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
    print 'started your instances: ' + str(instances)
```

Lamda role

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:Start*",
        "ec2:Stop*"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can read more details about this approach [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/start-stop-lambda-cloudwatch/) and [here](https://www.thinkforwardmedia.com/automating-ec2-instances-aws-lambda/).

**Using AWS cli and Cron Job**

stop.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
ID="i-1234567890abcdef0"
echo "stop instance having ID=$ID
aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids $ID
```

start.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "starting instance....."
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-1234567890abcdef0
```

**cron job**

To stop

`0 0 * * * stop.sh`
To start

`0 7 * * * start.sh`

Using the second approach you will be saving resources and cost of Lamda function.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to use [AWS Instance Scheduler](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/instance-scheduler/). There is a demo video at https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/stop-start-instance-scheduler/